# Hibernate ManyToMany prevent association removal on entity delete

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to delete entity without deleting many-to-many relation (not the referenced entity!)

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    //I want this data to be strictly read only! 
    //It's inserted, deleted and managed from referenced entity
    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_to_data",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Data> datas;

}
```

Generated delete looks like

```
delete 
from
    person_to_data
where
    person_id=?
    
delete 
from
    person 
where
    id=?
```

Due to documentaion, it's a valid delete
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-unidirectional

See example 169:

By simply removing the parent-side, Hibernate can safely remove the associated link records as you can see in the following example:
Example 169. Unidirectional @ManyToMany entity removal

```
Person person1 = entityManager.find( Person.class, personId );
entityManager.remove( person1 );

DELETE FROM Person_Address
WHERE  Person_id = 1

DELETE FROM Person
WHERE  id = 1
```

My goal is to have a constraint violation, if entity with exising mtm collection entries is deleted. My DB  has ON DELETE contraints in m-to-m table, but since delete by person_id is executed, it's never reached.

I see different possible approaches:

1. Change ManyToMany anno to OneToMany. However, with JoinTable collection assosiation delete is still generated (why?)
2. Some annotation to prevent such behaviour/force constraint?

Comment: Not sure I follow this part: 'I want this data to be strictly read only! It's inserted, deleted and managed from referenced entity'. Why is it not the inverse side of the association, then?

Comment: @crizzis, in Person entity, I want to view attached Datas. Data's entity contains collection of PersonToData object (consisting of two links and extra data), which is saved&cascaded. I don't want PersonToData object in Person, just the direct collection of Data. I need it for readonly purpouse and it works fine, before I call delete

Comment: In that case, put `@Immutable` on top of `Person.datas`